# Furnace Condensate freezing on siding

Tags: hvac, freezing

I am helping a client with an issue related to the condensate line on their furnace.  It is a high efficiently LP furnace installed in an attic with a condensate line that drains to the exterior.  The line exits the house through the attic soffit.  The line was freezing so my HVAC tech installed heat tape to the interior portion of the line and shortened the exterior portion so that it only sticks a few inches below the soffit.  He also insulated the exterior portion.  Now the line no longer freezes but the draining condensate is forming large icicles on the siding.  What is the best way to protect the siding from the icicle build-up?  I hesitate to re-extend the exterior portion of the drain line because I fear it would freeze up again.  My first though is to install a vinyl gutter down the side of the house where the drain line exits to channel water toward the ground with the theory being that the larger circumference would make it less prone to freeze-ups.  Would this work, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: The condensate drain for the furnace burner should have never been run outside like that.  Old habits from air conditioner condensate lines I suppose.  Your best permanent solution is to find a way to run it to a drain inside.

Comment: @Tyson One caveat to what you said.  You *may* want to run an overflow (backup) drain to the outside, to alert the homeowner of a problem with the main drain.

Comment: Good point @Tester101